# Проблема с передачей цвета на видео opencv\imageio

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

Cобственно я долго мучался с opencv и решил что для моих нужд буду использовать imageio, не спрашивайте почему не могу с этим ничего поделать.
Проблема в том что imageio, насколько я понял, кодирует цвет читаемого видео в RGB, a opencv в BGR - что на выходе дает нам ужасную картинку(красный - синий, синий - красный, и т.п.). Как это пофиксить?
Вот код:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from imageio import get_reader

cv2.setUseOptimized(True)
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('face_cascades.xml')
filename = '/home/nomatterhowyoutry/Videos/15093878490593.webm'
vid = get_reader(filename,  'ffmpeg')

for i, im in enumerate(vid):
    image = vid.get_data(i)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    cv2.imshow('video', image)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

Поиграйте со строкой

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Попробуйте `COLOR_BGR2RGB`